# dplyr & gracefully dealing with SQL NULL values

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dplyr

I'm trying to use **dplyr** to work with **SQL** databases using **R** and I'd like to gracefully handle **SQL**'s NULL values--either by simply filtering them out or treating them as zeros when the come up, depending on the scenario--without making any changes to the underlying database itself. (In other words, I'm *not* asking about converting all NULL values to zero *from within* SQL.)

Basically, I'm trying to use **dplyr** to work with **SQL** databases but I keep getting unexpected results.

```
# Using Lahman's Database, available here:
# https://www.kaggle.com/seanlahman/the-history-of-baseball

library(dplyr)

db.path <- '~/data/SQLite Databases/the-history-of-baseball/database.sqlite'
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db.path)

batting_db <- tbl(con, 'batting')

# the result of this code is at least (seemingly) correct--the columns appear
# to be the correct type and the entries shown are all accurate:
batting_db %>% 
    filter(hr >= 50)

# however, when the additional constraint is added, columns get coerced to 
# characters and rows where hr == '' start showing up
batting_db %>% 
    filter(hr >= 50, year >= 1985)
```

First, why is this even an issue? Why wouldn't empty strings get filtered out since `'' >= 50` evaluates to FALSE? (Note: Adding the additional constraint that `hr != ''` appears to have fixed this behavior, though I still don't understand why...)

Also, as far as converting these empty strings to zero now I'm not even sure if that's necessary since apparently **dplyr** treats them as zero in calculations(?!).

```
# mutate appears to treat these empty strings as '0' in calculations
batting_db %>% 
    filter(hr >= 30, year >= 1985) %>%
    select(player_id:g, h, hr) %>%
    mutate(hr2 = hr + 5, hr3 = g * hr)
```

Basically, I'm just not getting a hold of **dplyr**'s behavior when using it to access databases and I'd appreciate any insight.

Comment: In your first attempt, did you notice all the warnings (16!) about how columns are mixed type, the first value it saw was an integer and so it coerced the whole column to integer...? In the second example, presumably a lot of that data is missing, so it only sees the `""` and leaves them as characters.

Comment: @joran, first off, just so we're on the same page, I'm going to say refer to each of the chunks starting with `batting_db %>%` as my three "examples", if that makes sense. Ok, with that said, the first example only returns two warnings affecting two (irrelevant) columns.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that we have different R/dplyr versions causing the behavior to be slightly different, but I downloaded that exact sqlite db and ran that code and got warnings on 16 columns. The fundamental problem here is that whoever made that db declared the columns to be numeric, but then stored empty strings in them, which is, not ideal, even tho sqlite lets you do it. Another option might be to use the data from the R Lahman package, which actually has NA values where appropriate.

Comment: Except I'm not actually trying to analyze the Lahman dataset--I have a different database with columns that have NULL values throughout and I am trying to get a sense of how  **dplyr** interacts with these NULLs since it's clearly different than merely having a bunch of empty strings in a data frame.

Comment: Well, then I'm confused, because your question is all about a db with empty strings where there should be NULLs. If your actual problem involves a db with NULLs, not empty strings, then maybe a different example would be better? In my experience dplyr (dbplyr, really) does a pretty good job of mapping R's NA behavior to NULLs, so for filtering, you'd do `is.na(var)` or `!is.na(var)` like you would in R.

Comment: @joran, I'm confused as well because I was thinking that those empty strings were dplyr's way of representing SQL's NULL values (as opposed to a NULL value in R)... All of this is really making my head hurt. Literally.

Comment: So while your example doesn't raise the question you are trying to answer, it is an interesting question. dplyr does convert empty strings to zeros IF the column has already been determined to be numeric.  That shouldn't happen but mixing two types it's a feature of sqllite that shouldn't be allowed, as joran points out.

Comment: @Art, that's also why I thought that was dplyr's way of representing SQL's NULL values (and neither empty strings nor NAs nor R Nulls): Because of the way you can end up using those columns in `mutate` and they are treated as *zeros*...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect, but don't know, that dplyr will turn any `NULL`s in a SQL database to `NA`. I can't create a data frame with `NULL`s to test since that is not a valid R construct. I would need to see an example.  If we assume that `NULL`s get changed to `NA`, this example will turn the NA's to zero AND work on a copy of the table, not modifying the database.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)

#create dummy SQL database
set.seed(123)
tax<-tibble(taxpayer_id=1:10,income=runif(10,50,60),income_misc=runif(10,0,5)) %>% 
  mutate(income_misc=ifelse(income_misc<2,NA,income_misc))
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbWriteTable(con,"tax_tbl",tax,overwrite=TRUE)


# now extract
tax_db <- tbl(con, 'tax_tbl')
tax_db
#> # Source:   table<tax_tbl> [?? x 3]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.22.0 [:memory:]
#>    taxpayer_id income income_misc
#>          <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1           1   52.9        4.78
#>  2           2   57.9        2.27
#>  3           3   54.1        3.39
#>  4           4   58.8        2.86
#>  5           5   59.4       NA   
#>  6           6   50.5        4.50
#>  7           7   55.3       NA   
#>  8           8   58.9       NA   
#>  9           9   55.5       NA   
#> 10          10   54.6        4.77

tax <- tax_db %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% #have to create a data frame, not database, to modify NAs
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))

dbDisconnect(con)

tax
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    taxpayer_id income income_misc
#>          <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1           1   52.9        4.78
#>  2           2   57.9        2.27
#>  3           3   54.1        3.39
#>  4           4   58.8        2.86
#>  5           5   59.4        0   
#>  6           6   50.5        4.50
#>  7           7   55.3        0   
#>  8           8   58.9        0   
#>  9           9   55.5        0   
#> 10          10   54.6        4.77
Created on 2019-02-20 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This solves the problem of a **poorly constructed SQL table** presented in the example above by converting all columns to type `character`, replacing empty strings with `NA` and converting back to `integer` where appropriate.  If you are trying to compute stats on the stats you certainly don't want missing values to be treated as zero, but you know that already.

```
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

db.path <- "database.sqlite"
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), db.path)
batting_db <- tbl(con, 'batting')

batting <- batting_db %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  as_tibble %>% # must be a data frame for na_if to work
  na_if("") %>%  #replace empty strings with NA
  #convert numerics back to numerics
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of(c("player_id","team_id","league_id"))),as.integer)

# add a new table to the database with our clean data
dbWriteTable(con,"batting_mod",batting,overwrite=TRUE)
# back to where we started from but with a clean table
batting_db <- tbl(con, 'batting_mod')
batting_db

# Source:   table<batting_mod> [?? x 22]
# Database: sqlite 3.22.0 [C:\Users\nsteinm\Documents\R\temp\database.sqlite]
   player_id  year stint team_id league_id     g    ab     r     h double triple    hr   rbi    sb
   <chr>     <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>     <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 abercda01  1871     1 TRO     NA            1     4     0     0      0      0     0     0     0
 2 addybo01   1871     1 RC1     NA           25   118    30    32      6      0     0    13     8
 3 allisar01  1871     1 CL1     NA           29   137    28    40      4      5     0    19     3
 4 allisdo01  1871     1 WS3     NA           27   133    28    44     10      2     2    27     1
 5 ansonca01  1871     1 RC1     NA           25   120    29    39     11      3     0    16     6
 6 armstbo01  1871     1 FW1     NA           12    49     9    11      2      1     0     5     0
 7 barkeal01  1871     1 RC1     NA            1     4     0     1      0      0     0     2     0
 8 barnero01  1871     1 BS1     NA           31   157    66    63     10      9     0    34    11
 9 barrebi01  1871     1 FW1     NA            1     5     1     1      1      0     0     1     0
10 barrofr01  1871     1 BS1     NA           18    86    13    13      2      1     0    11     1
# ... with more rows, and 8 more variables: cs <int>, bb <int>, so <int>, ibb <int>, hbp <int>,
#   sh <int>, sf <int>, g_idp <int>
```

Comment: In this case I actually *do* want to treat them as zero because in the database itself the NULLs aren't missing values, they are, in effect, "N/A" values and *can* be treated as zero. For example, think of a column representing "misc. income" (note: I'm not sure *why* NULLs instead of zero would be desirable, but that's beside the point). More importantly, however, I *do not* want to make any changes to the underlying database itself.